# Very long delete operation

Tags: windows-8.1, ssd, window

Very often my files are deleted very slowly. Especially if I ask system delete large amount of files. For example I need to delete directory with size ~4Gb. Why I need to wait longer than one day?
[image]

Even thorougher I'm owner  256 Gb SSD disc. Yes, it is almost full, but it is SSD!

Comment: A 4GB file should be deleted within seconds not hours or days.  This indicates the drive is either starting to fail or the problem is a matter of free space.  SSDs are designed with wear leveling a full SSD's performance can be impacted by the amount of storage available and depending on the age the amount of storage left invisible and available to the OS for the purposes of wear leveling.  The first step is get some free space and verify the problem isn't solved by simply doing that.

Comment: They did not say 4gb file but 4gb directory which could have thousands of files or more.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell you if your SSD is healthy or not so I cannot judge if deleting a sack of tiny files must necessarily be that long.
However, it's a fact that copying and or even removing 4G of small files takes orders of magnitude longer that 4G containing just a couple of them.

During those actions the OS has to update/delete the meta data in addition to the blocks of the files. If indexing is allowed, even the index data must be touched. When you manipulate relatively big files, you don't recognize how long it takes to administer the content of the file system but when the difference is not big between the write time of the meta and the real data, big volume can make even a strong man cry.

It will not hurt to check the health of your disk, but once you are in business again, I recommend switching indexing off wherever it's not really required and creating a package (zip, rar, whatever) of the files and deleting them regularly if they don't have to be online permanently.